# ML110 G6 stuck at startup POST message issue

Tags: hp-proliant

I have an HP Proliant ML110 G6 server and I replaced the thermal paste on the CPU. As soon as I turned it back on, I noticed that the LED7 (BMC activity) was blinking, the fans were running at full speed and the boot process would stop at a mouse initialised message.

I tried to remove all hard drives, change position and resit the RAM modules and resit the CPU. I also removed the battery. Whatever I do the server gets stuck at the mouse initialised message and there is no way to bypass it or enter the bios.

The motherboard documentation can be found on the link below:

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c01925665

I am not sure how to restore it. Anyone with similar experience? Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any luck connecting to the IPMI/LOM?

Comment: You mean through the iLO interface? Not sure how to do it actually. Any suggestions?

Comment: So, I entered iLO management interface and strangely the system log shows everything in OK status. Is there anything specific to check inside iLO?

Comment: Nothing I can think of immediately, sorry. You could try /r/homelab or calling their support maybe.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably have to do that eventually...